# Uploading directly to S3 and resizing the images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm using [s3_direct_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) to directly upload images from my rails app to an S3 bucket. This is all working fine, however now I'd like to resize the images once uploaded, creating a thumbnail and various other versions.

The approach I can think of taking is using the URL that's posted back from s3_direct_upload to then create a new object in my app in the background, process using RMagick and then reupload these versions to S3.  However, this approach feels like the initial upload becomes a little redundant.

Any advice on this or a better approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

You mentioned in a comment to my original answer that you'd tried CarrierWave. But...have you tried out [CarrierWaveDirect](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct)? I haven't used it myself, but it appears to perform the same S3 direct-uploading, with the familiar API of CarrierWave.

---

**Original Deprecated Answer**

You'll probably want to look into either [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly). They each support uploading images to S3 (or other cloud storage provider), and also provide features for manipulating the images. The two solutions handle manipulations in different ways--Paperclip performs thumbnailing at upload-time, whereas Dragonfly performs thumbnailing on-the-fly--but either should meet your needs.

Comment: I was using Carrierwave, but what happened was if the user uploaded several images it tied up the app triggering a timeout.  I would anticipate using an image library to process the URL from the first s3 upload to create a number of new versions of it.

Comment: Ah, I understand the issue now. Hmm. I believe I've handled this scenario before, using Dragonfly. I just have to find the project. I'll revise my answer when I find it. ;)

Comment: I would love to know if anyone found a solution to this